# How do I skip splitting when white space occurs?

Tags: java, regex, split

I want to split using `";"` as delimiter and put outcome into the list of strings, for example

Input:

```
sentence;sentence;sentence
```

should produce:

```
[sentence, sentence, sentence]
```

Problem is some strings are like this:
`"sentence; continuation;new sentence"`, and for such I'd like the outcome to be: `[sentence; continuation, new sentence]`.

I'd like to skip splitting when there is whitespace after (or before) semicolon.

Example string I'd like to split:

```
String sentence = "Ogłoszenie o zamówieniu;2022/BZP 00065216/01;"Dostawa pojemników na odpady segregowane (900 sztuk o pojemności 240 l – kolor żółty; 30 sztuk o pojemności 1100 l – kolor żółty).";Zakład Wodociągów i Usług Komunalnych EKOWOD Spółka z ograniczoną odpowiedzialnością"
```

I tried:

```
String[] splitted = sentence.split(";\\S");
```

But this cuts off the first character of each sentence.

Comment: Whiteline? Do you mean white space?

Comment: show your code please

Comment: `String[] splitted = sentence.split(";(?=\\S)");`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex negative lookahead/lookbehind for this.

```
String testString = "hello;world; test1 ;test2";

String[] splitString = testString.split("(?<! );(?! )"); // Negative lookahead and lookbehind

for (String s : splitString) System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
hello
world; test1 ;test2
```

Here, the characters near the start and end of the regex are saying "only split on the semicolon if there are **no spaces before or after it**"